# mod_rewrite on .htaccess to map main folder to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying a simple thing: Make Apache 2.2.15 respond to all requests to `http://myserver/myfolder/*` with `http://myserver/myfolder/myproject/*` (Except those to `myproject`)

So far I've tried placing several variants of the following `.htaccess` on `myfolder`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^myproject
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myproject/$1 [L]
```

why do I get a 500 internal error?

Comment: Quick guess: `%{REQUEST_URI}` starts with a `/`.... If not, check your error logs, enable a rewrite log, check that, etc.

Comment: no, I tried that too.

Comment: Do you have `.htaccess` inside `myproject` ?

Comment: error log doesn't help much, just says more than 10 recursions or something. I guess it's not an obvious mistake I'm making?

Comment: @anubhava no, I don't have any other .htaccess

Comment: @elcodedocle:so, what does your rewrite log say?

Comment: error_log says: `.htaccess: RewriteLog not allowed here` tried setting the directive on .htaccess and httpd.conf right next to error_log directive, and also different error log paths.. same message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
RewriteBase /myfolder/

RewriteRule ^((?!myproject/).*)$ myproject/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: still same error:  `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Do you have any other rule in .htaccess? Try adding this before other rules.

Comment: See edit above with additional `RewriteBase /myfolder/` line.

Comment: Forgot to mention I removed `/` before `myproject` also in target.

Comment: I figured out the problem was `myfolder` and `myproject` actually have the same value (the project name), so I was somehow catching `myfolder` on my condition, when I should only catch `myproject`. Doing the negative lookahead, not only you put the condition inside the rule, but also avoid selecting it. Clever.

Comment: Yes exactly that's what happened. Advantage of negative lookahead in `RewriteRule` inside a sub directory is that you don't need to match full path.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is failing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^myproject
```

All `%{REQUEST_URI}` vars have a leading slash.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myproject
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myproject/$1 [L]
```

Or if the myproject can be anywhere:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myproject
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myproject/$1 [L]
```

---

If the htaccess file is in the `/myfolder` directory then try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder/myproject
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myproject/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Well I guess not this one. I tried like that too before posting, and there was no rewriting at all, the condition failed (e.g. `http://myserver/myfolder` just showed myfolder contents instead of `http://myserver/myfolder/myproject` contents)

Comment: still the same results, I also tried rewritebase before posting, sorry for not mentioning all the combinations I tried but some of them just didn't seem relevant. I mean, simple redirects worked without rebasing, it's just when I try to match anything inside the folder in one rule and put it on $1 when it fails